# 2 instances of one web page in 2 windows

Tags: browser

If I open www.google.com in chrome  and then I clear history and open www.google.com in another chrome page ,how can I distinguish these 2 web site? Is there something in one instance of browser which make it unique from other one?(same browser and same web page but 2 windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances - no. If you aren't talking about google.com, and instead are talking about a webpage that you develop - then you can have a javascript variable (not a cookie) that's set and sent along with page navigation.

As long as that variable is unique (or random) - you can distinguish the instances. 
Cookies are shared between single browser multiple windows/tabs unless using "Privacy mode"

More information on what you're trying to accomplish would help better answer this question.

Comment: Can you explain more about "privacy mode"?cookies will be unique in privacy mode?

Comment: Correct, in [privacy mode](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464) the new instance of the browser acts as if you've never opened a browser before. Try viewing stackoverflow in "incognito" while you're logged in - you will not be logged in in there.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP Protocol is stateless by nature so in general you shouldn't be able to tell. However, you have have two separate sessions open you can track traffic by inspecting the HTTP headers for session cookie values, but that's about as good as you're going to get.